# Full version of Soucaliuc's research announcement "Réflexion entre deux diffusions conjuguées"

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Florin Soucaliuc published the following research announcement in 2002 containing some results from his thesis on reflected diffusion processes:

[1] F. Soucaliuc, **Réflexion entre deux diffusions conjuguées**. [Reflection between two conjugate diffusions] C. R. Math. Acad. Sci. Paris 334 (2002), no. 12, 1119–1124. [Journal Link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S1631-073X(02)02376-2)

I have been unable to find a followup paper containing full proofs or to access the thesis:

[2] F. Soucaliuc, **Réflexion, coalescence et retournement du temps pour certaines familles de diffusions**, Thèse de doctorat, Université Paris-Sud, 2001.

as it appears to be available in two libraries in Paris.

Does a followup paper containing proofs to [1] exist anywhere, or is there a copy of [2] in .pdf?

Comment: I found the following [link](http://hdl.handle.net/10068/830872).  However, it does not seem to point to a hyperlink containing a PDF file for Soucaliuc's doctoral thesis.

Comment: Yes, it links to [Sudoc](http://www.sudoc.abes.fr/DB=2.1/SRCH?IKT=12&TRM=071379444), which to my understanding is accessible only from a French university (possibly in person).